# Orphaned purchase order in google play console

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-console, in-app-subscription, google-play-billing

We have recently introduce in-app purchases through subscriptions into our app.

Today, we saw a purchase order which was successfully placed and shows up under 'Order Management' in Google Play Console too. But I find no trace of it in our backend which creates an entry right after the payment is confirmed. But in this case, it didn't happen. Now there is no way for me to trace as to who the user here is. The user has also not reached out to us yet. How should we go about this?

It is really weird that the order id can't be traced back to the user on Play Console.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

AB

Comment: What is the order status for that purchase?

Comment: It says 'Active'.